# How to fix "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, docker-desktop

FYI:

1. I run Kubernetes on docker desktop for mac
2. The website based on Nginx image

I run 2 simple website deployments on Kubetesetes and use the NodePort service. Then I want to make routing to the website using ingress. When I open the browser and access the website, I get an error 503 like images below. So, how do I fix this error?

```
### Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-svc
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: app1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app2-svc
  labels:
    app: app2
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: app2

### Ingress-Rules
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: app-svc
          servicePort: 30092
      - path: /app2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2-svc
          servicePort: 30936
```

[image]

Comment: Try to set your service with type `ClusterIP`, instead of `NodePort` and set the servicePort to 80

Comment: @Jonas I get error 404 after change service type to ClusterIP.

Comment: What http headers do you get on the 404? Is the Server Header similar to openresty? Did you tried to access your nginx-ingress by following <your-ip>:<nginx-ingress-node-port>/app1?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, i end up with same error. once i changed the service type to "ClusterIP", it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Found this page after searching for a solution to nginx continually returning 503 responses despite the service names all being configured correctly.  The issue for me was that I had configured the kubernetes service in a specific namespace, but did not update the ingress component to be in the same namespace.  Despite being such a simple solution it was not at all obvious!

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use service type ClusterIP
Take look on this useful article: [services-kubernetes](https://www.ovh.com/blog/getting-external-traffic-into-kubernetes-clusterip-nodeport-loadbalancer-and-ingress/).

If you use Ingress you have to know that Ingress isn’t a type of Service, but rather an object that acts as a reverse proxy and single entry-point to your cluster that routes the request to different services. The most basic Ingress is the NGINX Ingress Controller, where the NGINX takes on the role of reverse proxy, while also functioning as SSL. On below drawing you can see workflow between specific components of environment objects.

Ingress is exposed to the outside of the cluster via ClusterIP and Kubernetes proxy, NodePort, or LoadBalancer, and routes incoming traffic according to the configured rules.

Example of service definition:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-svc
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: app1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app2-svc
  labels:
    app: app2
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: app2
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I get 404 after change service to ClusterIP.

Comment: yes, even I got the 503 after change also.

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to change the service type of your `app-service` to `ClusterIP`, because the `Ingress` object is going to access these `Pods`(services) from inside the cluster. (ClusterIP service is used when you want to allow accessing a pod inside a cluster).

Second, Make sure the services are running by running `kubectl get services` and check the running services names against the names in `backend` section in `Ingress` routing rules

Answer (score 0):

Little late to this journey but here is my comment on the issue.
I was having the same issue and having the same environment. (Docker Desktop-based Kubernetes with WSL2)

a couple of items probably can help.

1. add the host entry in the rules section. and the value will be  kubernetes.docker.internal like below

```html
rules:
    - host: kubernetes.docker.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - path....
```

2. check the endpoints using `kubectl get services` to confirm that the same port is in your ingress rule definition for each of those backend services.

```html
backend:
  service:
    name: my-apple-service
      port:
        number: 30101
```

```
kubectl get services
```

```html
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
my-apple-service    ClusterIP   10.106.121.95   <none>        30101/TCP   9h
my-banada-service   ClusterIP   10.99.192.112   <none>        30101/TCP   9h
```